# Getting a generic Interface from Assembly instead of using typeof(Interface) have an unexpeted behavior

Tags: c#

I need to filter objects of a container base on the Interface they implement, one of them is Ibase, this will do it for known interfaces:

```
selObjs = container.Where(component => typeof(Ibase).IsAssignableFrom(component.GetType())).ToList();
```

But I get the interface names from a config file so as the Interface can't be instantiated, I'm unable to use a variable attached to GetType(), additionally the use of a switch is not practical, so I'm getting the Interface type from the Assembly.

```
string interfaceName = "IbaseG<Type>";
interfaceName = $"{interfaceName .Substring(0, interfaceName.IndexOf("<"))}`1";
Type selInterf = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                    .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Name, interfaceName, StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray()[0];
selObjs = Container.Where(component => selInterf.IsAssignableFrom(component.GetType())).ToList();
```

It works great for non-generic interfaces, but if the Interface is Generic, The Interface retrieved from the Assembly has the same name and GUID of the `typeof(IbaseG<Type>)` but the Type and FullName are different, and it doesn't match using IsAssignableFrom.

This is a small Console App that show the differences between Generic and Non-Generic Interfaces

```
namespace ConsoleApp {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface IbaseG<T> { T Val { get; } }
public class BaseG<T> : IbaseG<T> {
    public T Val { get; }
    public BaseG() { }
}
public class ExtG<T> : BaseG<T> {
    public ExtG() { }
}

public interface Ibase { string Val { get; } }
public class Base : Ibase {
    public string Val { get; }
    public Base() { }
}
public class Ext : Base {
    public Ext() { }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Test");

        bool isAssignable = typeof(IbaseG<string>)
             .IsAssignableFrom(new ExtG<string>().GetType()); //  true

        // Non Generic Type
        Test("Ibase", typeof(Ibase), new Ext());

        // Generic Type
        Test("IbaseG<string>", typeof(IbaseG<string>), new ExtG<string>());

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static void Test(string interName, Type typeofType, object obj) {
        if (typeofType.IsGenericType)
            interName = $"{interName.Substring(0, interName.IndexOf("<"))}`1";

        Type assmType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Name, interName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                .ToArray()[0];

        Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        results.Add($"assembly.GetType({assmType.Name})
                       .IsAssignableFrom({obj.GetType().Name}) 1", 
                     (assmType.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()).ToString()));
        results.Add($"typeof({typeofType.Name})
                       .IsAssignableFrom({obj.GetType().Name}) 2", 
                     (typeofType.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()).ToString()));
        results.Add("Same Type", (assmType == typeofType).ToString()); // true
        results.Add("Same Name", (assmType.Name == typeofType.Name).ToString()); // true
        results.Add("Same FullName", (assmType.FullName == typeofType.FullName).ToString()); // true
        results.Add("Same GUID", (assmType.GUID == typeofType.GUID).ToString()); // true

        if (assmType.IsGenericType)
            Console.WriteLine($"Generic Type: {interName} Results");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Non Generic Type: {interName} Results");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> result in results)
            Console.WriteLine($"{result.Key}: {result.Value}");

        Console.WriteLine($"typeof({typeofType.Name}).FullName: {typeofType.FullName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"assembly.GetType({assmType.Name}).FullName: {assmType.FullName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"typeof({typeofType.Name}).GUID: {typeofType.GUID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"assembly.GetType({assmType.Name}).GUID: {assmType.GUID}");
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because "Ibase'1" is  `typeof(Ibase<>)` you need to create concrete type using `Type.MakeGenericType` ... like `typeof(Ibase<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string))` [see this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DdwPzX)

Comment: Tank for your answer but in this case MakeGenericType force the object to 'implement'the interface, and what I need is check if the object implements the interface, so solution should be doing `typeof(IbaseG<String>).IsAssignableFrom( new ExtG<String>());` without something that can use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

based of @Selvin comment.

The Interface retrieved from the assembly has to be MakeGenericType of the same type as the object:

```
// ExtG<Type> implements the intreface IbaseG<Type> 
string interName = "IbaseG<Type>";
Type typeofType = typeof(IbaseG<Type>);
object obj = new ExtG<Type>();

if (typeofType.IsGenericType)
    interName = $"{interName.Substring(0, interName.IndexOf("<"))}`1";

Type assmType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
        .Where(t => String.Equals(t.Name, interName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        .ToArray()[0];

if (typeofType.IsGenericType)
    assmType = assmType.MakeGenericType(typeof(Type));

bool test1 = typeof(IbaseG<Type>).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()); //true
bool test2 = (assmType.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())); // true
```

Comment: You need recursion for fx `Ibase<IEnumerable<string>>`